# Show $f(x,y)=x^7+yx^5+yx^3+3yx+y\in R[x,y]$ is irreducible in $R[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a UFD and consider
$$
f(x,y) = x^7 + yx^5 + yx^3 + 3yx + y \in R[x,y].
$$
Show that $f(x,y)$ is irreducible in $R[x,y]$.

Proof: Note $R[x,y]=R[y][x]$. Let $S=R[y]$. We will show $f(x,y)$ is irreducible in $S[x]$. By Eisenstein Criterion, let $p=y$. (How do I know y is prime in $S[x]$?) We can see

- $y | a_0=a_1=a_2=a_3=y, a_4=0$
- $y\not | a_5=1$
- $y^2 \not | a_0=y$
  Hence $f(x,y)$ is irreducible in $S[x]$.

Am I done?

Comment: View f as a polynomial in x with coefficients in R[y] and use y as a prime. (Don't forget that R[y] is a UFD, too.)

Comment: I get the idea but how do I formally write it up?

Comment: Correction. How do I write that I can play with $R[y]$ from $R[x,y]$?

Comment: R[x,y]=R[y][x]. Set S=R[y] and use Eisenstein in S[x].

Comment: I updated my post with a rough draft of a proof. How does it look?

Comment: It looks good, excepting the missing proof for y prime in S which can be shown by noticing that S/(y)=R[y]/(y) is isomorphic to R, and R is an integral domain, so (y) is a prime ideal in S, and hence y is a prime element in S.